# Modify the beginning and the end of line if match

Tags: bash, sed

Is there a way to replace all lines in a file, from

`title={WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE}`

to

`title={{WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE}}`

and to preserve whatever is inside unmodified. Note: WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE is always a different strig, so I would need * or so...

Comment: Yes there is a way. It's a good excercise to learn about `sed` and backreferences. You can learn about regex in [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/) and other games online, you can learn about sed in [this sed introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) , but really googling "sed backreference" will give you a ton of help.

Answer (score 1):

Input `input.txt` :

```
title={WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE}
hello
title={IS_INSIDE_WHATEVER}
world
```

Command :

```
sed '/title={.*}/s,{,{{,g;/title={.*}/s,},}},' input.txt
```

Gives you on stdout :

```
title={{WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE}}
hello
title={{IS_INSIDE_WHATEVER}}
world
```

Comment: nit: sed returns 0.  The text shown above is the output, not the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
echo "title={WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE}" | sed -E "s/({)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(})/\1\1\2\3\3/g"
```

Output

```
title={{WHATEVER_IS_INSIDE}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
sed -e '/^title={[^}]*}$/s/{\(.*\)}/{{\1}}/'
```

or:

```
sed -E -e '/^title={[^}]*}$/s/{(.*)}/{{\1}}/'
```

and you'd probably be okay with the simpler:

```
sed -E -e '/title=/s/{(.*)}/{{\1}}/'
```

or:

```
awk '/^title=/{$2=sprintf("{%s}",$2)}1' FS== OFS==
```